# How to implement database trigger in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, triggers

I trying to implement database trigger in codeigniter, I want to update one specific table after the insert operation on other specific table. I am trying the following code but it not work for me.
**this is function I written in my model:**

```
<?php
public function enter_follower($follower_id, $following_id) {
$data = array('follower_user' => $follower_id,
             'following_user' => $following_id
            );  
$this->db->insert('followers', $data);
//return $this->db->insert_id();

$this->db->query("
CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateFollower` AFTER INSERT ON followers
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE business_users SET followerCount = followerCount + 1 WHERE user_id = $following_id
END");
if ($this->affected_rows() > 0) {
 return true
} else {
 return false
}

} ?>
```

Comment: why dont you just update the db instead of creating a trigger. plus youve created the trigger after the insert, it should go before. but really you shouldn't be doing it that way

Comment: I also assume that option but I want to know how should implement this using trigger.

Comment: hardcode it into your db schema because a trigger is only set once